# Display UIImage Instead of TableView if Empty

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uiimageview

I have a NSFetchResultsController that loads up my tableview.

When the app is first downloaded, there will be no data to show in the tableview so I want to have a static image with instructions on it.  I have the following code and I call this method in `viewWillAppear` but it doesn't function right.  Any ideas?

```
- (void)checkIfEmpty
{
    if ([self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] > 0)
    {
        self.defaultImage.hidden = NO;
        self.logTableView.hidden = YES;
    }
    else
    {
        self.defaultImage.hidden = YES;
        self.logTableView.hidden = NO;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is happening? what do you see?

Comment: "It doesn't fuction right" isn't very helpful. What does it do exactly, does it crash, does it always go in the first branch of the `if` statement, … your question is not detailed enough to be answered properly

Comment: My guess is that you have a UIViewController with a table withing it, not a UITableViewController, am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] > 0` will always be true because even an empty array is an object (and not `nil`).

You need to use `self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects.count > 0` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the same code in viewDidAppear . Try using alpha = 0 instead of hidden. Try putting the same code in one of your tableview delegate methods. Since you don't explain exactly what occurs I'm just throwing stuff out there.